# Mongodb aggregator is this good way of coding?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have orders.

```
       [{
        _id:'0',
            userId: 'zoo',
            paid : [{status:'done'},{stauts:'pending'}],
            type:'tennis'},{
        _id : '1',
            userId: 'zqq',
            paid : [{stautus :'done'},
            type : 'cricket']
            },{
       _id:'2',
       userId:'zqq',
       paid:[{status:'done'}],
       type:'tennis'}
]
```

i did aggregation like this

```
orders.aggregate([{
                    '$group':{
                        '_id' : '$userId',
                        'paid' : {$push:'$paid.status'},
                        'type' : {$push : '$type'}
                    }
                }])
```

In the end i get paid and type in array can i relay on the data that both of them are of the same order.
Is their any better solution.
I'm new to aggregation in mongodb sorry if i'm doing wrong

Comment: If you rely on order then you need to do it is explicitly after since you cannot rely on it

Comment: @sammaye so your telling it works fine??

Comment: Not if you rely on sort as you say you do, if you need a specific sort and for it to be the same you need to manually sort it using $sort after the $group